# How to hide and show a column in html table based on a php condition

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to hide and show a column in html table based on a php condition.

```
$gid = $_SESSION['gid'];

if(gid == NO) 
{
      //display whole table 

}
else{
        // Dont dispaly the certain columns like gst,sgst.
}
```

The table would look like

```
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Sl no</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Spares Particulars</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Amount</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Quantity</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">GST %</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">GST AMT</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">CGST %</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">CGST AMT</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">SGST %</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">SGST AMT</th>
    <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Total AMT</th>
     </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo $i ?></td>
<td><?php echo $sparen ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row9['amt'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row9['quant'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row9['gstp'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo round($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100)) ?></td>
<td><?php echo round($row9['gstp']/2) ?></td>
<td><?php echo round(($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100))/2) ?></td>
<td><?php echo round($row9['gstp']/2) ?></td>
<td><?php echo round(($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100))/2) ?></td>
<td><?php echo round((($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100))+$row9['amt'])*$row9['quant']) ?></td>

</tr>                            
</tbody>
</table>
```

I don't want the columns like `gst,gstamt,cgst,cgstamt,sgst,sgstamt` to be displayed if the gid=YES. The problem is I tried js for it but that's not working. Can someone help me out with an easier solution.

Comment: set a variable at page top and add IF condition in HTML part to show or hide by checking that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$gid = $_SESSION['gid'];
?>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Sl no</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Spares Particulars</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Amount</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Quantity</th>
        <?php if ($gid != 'YES') { ?>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">GST %</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">GST AMT</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">CGST %</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">CGST AMT</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">SGST %</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">SGST AMT</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Total AMT</th>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sparen ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row9['amt'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row9['quant'] ?></td>
        <?php if ($gid != 'YES') { ?>
        <td><?php echo $row9['gstp'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round($row9['amt'] * ($row9['gstp'] / 100)) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round($row9['gstp'] / 2) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round(($row9['amt'] * ($row9['gstp'] / 100)) / 2) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round($row9['gstp'] / 2) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round(($row9['amt'] * ($row9['gstp'] / 100)) / 2) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round((($row9['amt'] * ($row9['gstp'] / 100)) + $row9['amt']) * $row9['quant']) ?></td>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP ternary operator and css display property for that task

```
$ShowHide = ($gid == 'NO') ? 'block' : 'none';
<td style="display:<?php echo $ShowHide; ?>;"><?php echo round($row9['gstp']/2) ?></td>
```

I think this one of simple method to do the task. `$ShowHide` will set display property to `td` according to `$gid` value.

Comment: this not working properly, the values are yet displaying but outside the table.

Comment: @VipulRao this is only for one `td` you have to follow same step for all as you wanted

Comment: @VipulRao can you let me know what are you getting in `style="??"` ?

Comment: Even thats none

Answer (score 1):

Set flag variable value at top:

```
 $gid = $_SESSION['gid'];

    if(gid == NO) 
    {
         $flag = true;

    }
    else{
            $flag = false;
    }


    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Sl no</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Spares Particulars</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Amount</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Quantity</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">GST %</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">GST AMT</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">CGST %</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">CGST AMT</th>
<?php if($flag) { ?>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">SGST %</th>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">SGST AMT</th>
<?php } ?>
        <th class="border-0 text-uppercase small font-weight-bold">Total AMT</th>
         </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <tr>
    <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $sparen ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row9['amt'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row9['quant'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row9['gstp'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo round($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100)) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo round($row9['gstp']/2) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo round(($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100))/2) ?></td>

<?php if($flag) { ?>    
    <td><?php echo round($row9['gstp']/2) ?></td>
    <td><?php echo round(($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100))/2) ?></td>
<?php } ?>

    <td><?php echo round((($row9['amt']*($row9['gstp']/100))+$row9['amt'])*$row9['quant']) ?></td>

    </tr>                            
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

and check in HTML part to show/hide TD title and their respective values.